# API query to retrieve Salesforce Incident History

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to build an automation to get the Incident History of a Salesforce ticket. The incident history looks like a table as shown below:

[image: Incident History of a single ticket].

Is there an API query that can be used to get this data?

I have the api to create a session id and get the data of individual fields in a ticket. But this does not include the Incident History table.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.tracking_field_history.htm&type=5

> Salesforce stores an object’s tracked field history in an associated
> object called StandardObjectNameHistory or CustomObjectName__History.
> For example, AccountHistory represents the history of changes to the
> values of an Account record’s fields. Similarly,
> MyCustomObject__History tracks field history for the MyCustomObject__c
> custom object.

If your incident is really a `Case`:

```soql
SELECT Id, Field, OldValue, NewValue, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Name, CaseId, Case.Subject, Case.CaseNumber
FROM CaseHistory
LIMIT 10
```

And if it's `Incident__c`:

```
SELECT Id, Field, OldValue, NewValue, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Name, ParentId, Parent.Name
FROM Incident__History
LIMIT 10
```

I think there's only 1 exception to this rule - Opportunity has [OpportunityHistory](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunityhistory.htm) & [OpportunityFieldHistory](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunityfieldhistory.htm)

Some more info: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_hist.htm

Comment: Thank you. I was able to formulate the query to get the incident history. However, I wanted to use a where condition: WHERE ParentId is passed as a list of the incident ids to retrieve only those records that are required. I have tried creating a list constructor such as "List<string> Parent_Id". However, I am getting a "MALFORMED_QUERY: unexpected token: List" error. I am using <workbench.developerforce.com> to run queries.

Comment: If you're using "raw" SOQL (you mentioned API so I guess requests coming from another system) you need `WHERE ParentId IN ('a01...', 'a01...', 'a01...')` syntax. 100K max length, no bind variables/prepared statements. If you're using Apex - a bind variable should do the trick. `List<Id> myList = new List<Id>{'a01...', 'a01...'}; System.debug([SELECT Field FROM Incident__History WHERE ParentId IN :myList]);`

Comment: Got it. I was using double quotes in the WHERE ParentId IN ("a01...", "a01...") earlier which was giving me issues. Thank you.